# Can height rises/falls be added to the station plots in a DIFAX chart replica?

Tags: python, metpy

First, I would like to thank Kevin Goebbert and the MetPy team for providing this very helpful Python code for creating a DIFAX chart replica: https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/Upperair_Obs.html. I just have a quick question regarding this code: Can values of height rises/falls be added to these DIFAX replicas, similar to the legacy products themselves? If so, how would I go about doing that? Here is an example DIFAX chart to illustrate what I am referring to: http://archive.atmos.colostate.edu/data/misc/QHTA11/0701/07013113QHTA11.png. The height rises/falls are displayed for some radiosonde stations in the bottom right-hand corner of the station plots.

Thanks for your time and assistance!

Jordan McLeod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the changes to make are:

1. Use a `timedelta(hours=12)` to figure out what the right time is for the previous data
2. Align the `DataFrame`s using `set_index('station')` so that you can subtract the two `height` columns to get the change
3. Plot with `plot_parameter` using a custom formatter to plot in dm with +/- sign

The whole product for the station plotting then works out as

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from metpy.io import add_station_lat_lon
from metpy.plots import StationPlot
from siphon.simplewebservice.iastate import IAStateUpperAir

level = 500

# Set date for desired UPA data
today = datetime.utcnow()

# Go back one day to ensure data availability
date = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 0) - timedelta(days=1)

# Previous is 12 hours before that time
prev = date - timedelta(hours=12)

# Request data using Siphon request for data from Iowa State Archive
data = IAStateUpperAir.request_all_data(date)
prev_data = IAStateUpperAir.request_all_data(prev)

# Given our data, add station information and drop any stations that are missing lat/lon. Then set
# 'station' as the index column so that operations between datasets will align on that column
data = add_station_lat_lon(data).dropna(how='any', subset=('longitude', 'latitude')).set_index('station')
prev_data = add_station_lat_lon(prev_data).dropna(how='any', subset=('longitude', 'latitude')).set_index('station')

# Create subset of all data for a given level
df = data[data.pressure == level].copy()
prev_df = prev_data[prev_data.pressure == level]

# Calculate the change on the aligned data frames--needs to be
# added to original dataframe to maintain consistent ordering
# with later use
df['height_change'] = df.height - prev_df.height

# Set up map coordinate reference system
mapcrs = ccrs.LambertConformal(
    central_latitude=45, central_longitude=-100, standard_parallels=(30, 60))

# Set up station locations for plotting observations
point_locs = mapcrs.transform_points(
    ccrs.PlateCarree(), df['longitude'].values, df['latitude'].values)

# Start figure and set graphics extent
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(17, 15))
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=mapcrs)
ax.set_extent([-125, -70, 20, 55])

# Add map features for geographic reference
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'), edgecolor='grey')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND.with_scale('50m'), facecolor='white')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'), edgecolor='grey')

# Start the station plot by specifying the axes to draw on, as well as the
# lon/lat of the stations (with transform). We also the fontsize to 10 pt.
stationplot = StationPlot(ax, df['longitude'].values, df['latitude'].values, clip_on=True,
                          transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), fontsize=10)

# Plot the temperature and dew point to the upper and lower left, respectively, of
# the center point.
stationplot.plot_parameter('NW', df['temperature'], color='black')
stationplot.plot_parameter('SW', df['dewpoint'], color='black')

# A more complex example uses a custom formatter to control how the geopotential height
# values are plotted. This is set in an earlier if-statement to work appropriate for
# different levels.
def hght_format(v):
    return format(v, '.0f')[:3]

stationplot.plot_parameter('NE', df['height'], formatter=hght_format)

# Add wind barbs
stationplot.plot_barb(df['u_wind'], df['v_wind'], length=7, pivot='tip')

# Add height falls. This converts the change to decameters with /10, then
# formats with a +/- and 0 padding
def height_fall_formatter(v):
    return f'{int(v / 10):+03d}'

# Plot the parameter with an italic font
stationplot.plot_parameter('SE', df['height_change'], formatter=height_fall_formatter,
                           fontstyle='italic')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is incredibly helpful! However, I can't seem to get the correct height rises/falls to display on the DIFAX chart. I cross-checked a sample DIFAX chart with the corresponding radiosonde data, and they didn't match up. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong? I can try to paste my code if needed.

Comment: There was a subtle bug in how I was using pandas in the original code that led to the height_change field being in a different order than the original dataframe. I've adjust the code to fix this issue.